# Straight line distance between two addresses - Google maps API

Tags: google-maps

Looking for a solution for measuring the straight line distance between two addresses using Google maps API, not the driving distance.

Answer (score 2):

First use google map geocoding API to find the lat/lng of your adresses:

[Google Map geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)

Then calculate distances between those two points using [Harvesine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)

Here is an example of the Haversine formula injs on a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27943/8282397)